# Regex for minimum of any two words and having total length greater than 5

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

In .net MVC application I need to regex to validate at least two words in a input and minimum lengths of input should be greater than 5.(special characters allowed are only "." and no numeric are allowed)

Currently I am using

```
^([a-zA-Z\.\s]{5,})+$.
```

It doesn't work for two words.

Comment: [`What have you tried`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might need something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z\.]{6,} [a-zA-Z]{6,} .+$
```

This will match 2 words as per your specification and then allow amount of characters thereafter.

Comment: Tip: for java or kotlin: ^[a-zA-Z.]{2,} [a-zA-Z]{2,}+$

Answer (score 1):

If total length of input should be greater than 5:
`"^([a-zA-Z.\\s]{6,})$"` - it works fine for me.

If length of every word should be greater than 5:
`"^([a-zA-Z]{6,}[\\s.]*)++$"`